# Build iOS Calendar like Day View using scrollview or collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, calendarkit

I've been trying to bring my app to iPad, and i wanted to implement a day view like there is in the iOS Calendar.

I found some awesome libraries on GitHub, which do almost everything i want, the problem is, that i want to use my custom event model, and a custom view, which can represent the my custom event.

[CalendarKit - GitHub](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)

[JZCalendarWeekView - GitHub](https://github.com/zjfjack/JZCalendarWeekView)

I have searched around, and found a good idea on StackOverflow, in which they said you could use a ScrollView, and the Events would be subviews of that scrollView. Some say a collection view could also do the job, but unfortunately i really could not get a good starting point, in how to do the view.

So let's imagine, i try the scrollview route, then i don't understand, how to make the separators with the hour marks?

[image]

I would really appreciate some good advice to get started.

Comment: Replicating a *"day view like there is in the iOS Calendar"* is a big task. Your best bet may be to take one of those libraries and just start digging through the code, modifying it to fit your design needs.

Comment: Please take a look at this video of how to add support for editing functionality with CalendarKit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KHTYsYs12w